# Google Spreadsheet notification emails

Tags: google-sheets, notifications

I have a spreadsheet whereby a user puts in their email address in column A and I populate columns B & C with data.

What I would like is for the user in column A to be notified when data is put into column B/C of the same row.

Is this possible?